# picqer get orders from specific date

Tags: api, vue.js, axios

I want to know if there is a way to look back at orders from a few days ago with the picqer API.

Looking at the filters and stuff on their website it doesn't look like you can with only the API. Is there a way to do it anyway?

(i am working with vue.js and axios for my requests idk if this is relevant)

Answer (score 0):

Casper from Picqer here. At this moment we do not have a filter for orders until a specific date. But if you are only looking for orders from the last few days, you could cycle trough the orders (100 items per request) until the date you want to get the orders from.

We have a suggestion noted for filtering orders in the API for a specific date. Did you notify our support team about this? Then we will notify you when that filter is available.

These are the filters we have active for the orders endpoint at this moment: https://picqer.com/en/api/orders#filters